# Does Redshift depends on wavelength?

Tags: velocity, wavelength, doppler-effect, redshift

I came across this equation on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift):
$$z=\frac{\lambda_{\text{observed}} - \lambda_{\text{emitted}}}{\lambda_{\text{emitted}}}$$
and it got me thinking: If I measure a wavelength of $700 \;\text{nm}$ compared to a rest wavelength of $656 \;\text{nm}$, that gives me a redshift of $0.097$.

So if every wavelength gets shifted by the same amount, in this case $720 - 656 = 64 \;\text{nm}$. Does that mean that the redshift value is different for every wavelength?

If not, every wavelength gets shifted by a different amount with a fixed redshift value?

How you calculate the velocity of a body in these scenarios?

Comment: What does it have to do with the velocity of a body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every wavelength doesn't get redshifted by the same absolute amount.

Every wavelength is multiplied by a *factor* of $1+z$.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain recessional velocity $v=dr/dt$ from redshift in flat spacetime, with no transverse motion: solve

$1+z = \gamma v/c$

where

$\gamma = (1-v^2/c^2)^{-2}$

for $v$

For apparent recessional velocity between objects stationary with respect to one another in an expanding spacetime, just use

$v = cz$